# Copying string into char array

Tags: c, arrays, string

i have a token of type char* that i want to get the second element of. For example the tokens all consist of a 4 long course number like `1405`, i want to grab the 2nd character or 4, and turn it into an interger. I use strcpy to add the string into a char string array in order to grab the 4 but i get some errors and im not quite sure how to fix them. here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int search(struct id array[],char* tok);


int main(void)
{

    char* token2 = "1405";
    char* text[] = malloc(strlen(token2)+1);
    strcpy(text,token2);
    int i,number;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        if(i==1)
        {
        number = atoi(token2[i]); }
    printf("%d\n",number);
```

i get the following compilation errors

```
gcc structures_arrayof.c
structures_arrayof.c: In function ‘main’:
structures_arrayof.c:23:20: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
     char* text[] = malloc(strlen(token2)+1);
                    ^
structures_arrayof.c:23:5: error: invalid initializer
     char* text[] = malloc(strlen(token2)+1);
     ^
structures_arrayof.c:24:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     strcpy(text,token2);
     ^
In file included from structures_arrayof.c:5:0:
/usr/include/string.h:129:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
```

Comment: text is just a char*, not an array of char *. Also include stdlib.h for malloc.

Comment: `malloc()` is in `<stdlib.h>`, which you didn't include. Anyway, your program is not complete. Heck, even your `main()` is not.

Comment: lol -too much coffee, not enough reading.  Sorry all...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan is char *text[] illegal? Wrong for sure, illegal not.

Comment: and `char* text[] = ` should be `char *text = `

Comment: `atoi` expects a string as input, not a `char`. For a `char`, `x-'0'` is quite sufficient anyway.

Comment: The indentation on the `if` statement and following assignment is one of the most extraordinary I've ever seen.  Please review the standard notations and adopt one of them and use it consistently.  (My choice is [Allman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), but there are plenty of alternatives to choose from.)

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` is for converting a *string* to integer. However, you want to convert a *single character*.

You can write:

```
number = token2[i] - '0';
```

This works because the digits `'0'` through `'9'` have consecutive character codes. There is no need to malloc or whatever.

Comment: glad someone posted this. Surprised at how few people realize this easy way to convert character digits to ints

Comment: You gonna address all the other deficits too?

Comment: @Deduplicator that was covered by "There is no need to malloc or whatever". The defective code can all be removed. (It's also covered by comments on the question in case anyone is curious). The question title could do with an edit though.

Answer (score 1):

To work with what you are doing....

This should clear up the first set of errors.

```
char* text = malloc(strlen(token2)+1);
```

You are need a pointer to a char string.

To do the the conversion, you need to null terminate the string.

```
token2[i+1]=0;
```

Then you can

```
number = atoi(token2[i]);
```

Comment: At the very least, you also need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` to fix the implicit declaration warning.

Answer (score 0):

**The first error:**
You forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get `malloc`.

**The second error:**
A string represented as a pointer to a `char`, so you just need
`char *text = malloc(strlen(token2)+1);`
Drop the brackets.
Alternatively, since size is known at compile time, you can declare it without `malloc` using `char text[5];`

**The third error:**
It warns you that you are using the wrong type of pointer. This should be fixed by changing the declaration as mentioned above.

**The fourth error** (not in your pasted compiler output):
As Matt McNabb pointed out, you should not be using atoi. Replace it with
`number = token2[i] - '0';` This will subtract the ASCII vaule of 0, returning the integer value of the character.

An additional comment: I'd recommend changing the spacing/indent style of the `if` statement. Putting an opening brace on its own line and a closing brace on the same line as the last statement is *very* non-conventional, and it decreases readability.
I suggest you pick a standard style and try to stick to it. Personally, I like the [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle), but feel free to choose whichever suits you.