# Parsing input data from a text file

Tags: c

What I need to do is open a file for reading with the following data. I have done pretty much everything with opening the file but I'm stuck on the part where I need to tokenize the info and add it to an array of structures. The input data looks like this:

```
John is enrolled in MATH 1426.
Peter is enrolled in SCI 1441.
John is enrolled in PHYS 1201.
```

This is what my `struct` looks like that I need to read data into:

```
struct classes {
  char name[20];
  char department[4];
  int course_number[4];
};
```

This is my code for opening and reading the file into the `struct` above:

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE *file;
  char buffer[50];
  char line[50];
  struct classes student;    

  file = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
  {
     tokenize = strtok(buffer, " ");
     strcpy(line, tokenize);
     while(tokenize != NULL)
     {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        switch(i)
        {
          case 3: strcpy(student.department, token);
             break;
          case 5: student.course_number = atoi(token);
        }
     }
     i++;
  }
  i=0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is tokenize the data into an array of structures, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question as stated says absolutely nothing about the *programming* problem, which is probably something about "tokenizing values and and placing them into arrays".

Comment: @PaulRichter I understood the programming problem from the OP's question. English probably isn't his or her first language, but I got the gist of it.

Comment: You mention "an array of structures", but there is no such thing in your code. And your code doesn't compile at all BTW.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that's why I'm here for the help I'm a newbee to C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24643613/971127

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes or the close votes either. This poster at least showed some effort. I see dozens and dozens of questions like this every day that demonstrate no effort whatsoever and yet they remain open with no downvotes. So I edited and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct classes {
    char name[20];
    char department[5];//+1 for '\0'
    int course_number;
};

int main(void){
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[50];
    struct classes student, students[48];
    int i, count=0;

    file = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)){
        //Format : NAME is enrolled in DEPARTMENT NUMBER.
        if(3 == sscanf(buffer, "%19s %*s %*s %*s %4s %d",
                student.name, student.department, &student.course_number))
                students[count++] = student;
    }
    fclose(file);
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        printf("%-*s %-*s %d\n",
            (int)sizeof(student.name), students[i].name,
            (int)sizeof(student.department), students[i].department,
            students[i].course_number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I finally figured it out but i'm stuck at the point where if the there more than two names that are same we should add the hours for example if `john is enrolled in MATH 1314` and John is enrolled in SCI 1402 it should add 3+4 and give hime his hours to be 7 and display `john, 7` instead of two names that are same.

Comment: @user3814932 You must set the course by the search if guarantee identity with a name.

Comment: I think you need a treatment, such as an array of department and courses in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given so far only shows the attempt at building the structure.

For strings, you need to have room for the null character at the end.

- department and course_number need to be larger

Your strtok tokens are aren't working because you need to strtok on " " not " ."

You will need to grab the 1st, 5th, and 6th iterations of strtok and put them into the corresponding fields in the stucture: name, department, and course number.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

1) `department` has 4 elements, which means there is no room for a terminating null if the department name has 4 characters.

2) `course_number` is declared as an `int` so it doesn't need to be an array.

3) However, you will have to convert course numbers to int using `atoi`, `sscanf` or something similar.

4) `student` is only a single instance, not an array of structs as it needs to be to contain multiple students.

5) When your outer loop terminates, `line` will contain the name "John", `student.name` will contain the text "1201", and `student.department` will contain garbage, as will `student.course_number`.

Fix those five problems and you will have a working program.

Comment: Thank you very much your input very much helped me solve it, If you don't mind I have edited the code to what I have working, what I want now is take the `course_number` for example `1426` for john since there are two johns I should add 4+2 to get total number of hours to be 6

Comment: A slight improvement but you're over-complicating this. Take a look at silverglade's answer. You don't need an inner loop. All you need is six calls to `strtok`, with the results of the 1st, 5th and 6th calls being the ones returning the data you want. Just make those six calls and forget the inner loop entirely.